# iOS Fabric compile fails after GIT branching

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, branch, google-fabric

I have an iOS project effectively using Fabric and Crashlytics. Everything works as expected until I branch my project and switch to the new branch.

The error is from the run script.

```
./foo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/bar-emsepzlotmiqgrbvfhqgiyivytkr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/bar.build/Debug-iphoneos/bar.build/Script-010652C22130393400A7E40F.sh: line 2: ./Fabric.framework/run: No such file or directory
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Most importantly seems to be the

```
./Fabric.framework/run: No such file or directory
```

and the question is, why does this happen on a GIT branch and that's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around the issue by changing my run script to:

```
${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/Fabric.framework/run
```

But I still would like to know what in the GIT branch causes the issue and if there is a better solution.